# Decoding incomplete audio file

Tags: audio, decode, wav, file-format

I was given an uncompressed .wav audio file (360 mb) which seems to be broken. The file was recorded using a small usb recorder (I don't have more information about the recorder at this moment). It was unreadable by any player and I've tried GSpot (https://www.headbands.com/gspot/) to detect whether it was perhaps of a different format than wav but to no avail. The file is big, which hints at it being in some uncompressed format. It misses the RIFF-WAVE characters at the start of the file though, which can be an indication this is some other format or perhaps (more likely in this case) the header is missing.

I've tried converting the bytes of the file directly to audio and this creates a VERY noisy audio file, though voices could be made out and I was able to determine the sample rate was probably 22050hz (given a sample size of 8-bits) and a file length of about 4 hours and 45 minutes. Running it through some filters in Audition resulted in a file that was understandable in some places, but still way too noisy in others.

Next I tried running the data through some java code that produces an image out of the bytes, and it showed me lots of noise, but also 3 byte separations every 1024 bytes. First a byte close to either 0 or 255 (but not 100%), then a byte representing a number distributed somewhere around 25 (but with some variation), and then a 00000000 (always, 100%). The first 'chunk header' (as I suppose these are) is located at 513 bytes into the file, again close to a 2-power, like the chunk size. Seems a bit too perfect for coincidence, so I'm mentioning it as it could be important. https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Do3.jpg, the first image shows a 1024x1024 image showing the first 1mb of the file (row-wise) and the second image shows the distribution of the 3 'chunk header' bytes.

Next to these headers, the file also has areas that clearly show structure, almost wave-like structures. I suppose this is the actual audio I'm after, but it's riddled with noise: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Do3.jpg, third image, showing a region of the file with audio structures.

I also created a histogram for the entire file (ignoring the 3-byte 'chunk headers'): https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Do3.jpg, fourth image. I've flipped the lower half of the range as I think audio data should be centered around some mean value, but correct me if I'm wrong. Maybe the non-symmetric nature of the histogram has something to do with signed/unsigned data or two's-complement. Perhaps the data representation is in 8-bit floats or something similar, I don't know.

I've ran into a wall now. I have no idea what else I can try. Is there anyone out there that sees something I missed. Perhaps someone can give me some pointers what else to try. I would really like to extract the audio data out of this file, as it contains some important information.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bother. I've been able to track down the owner of the voice recorder and had him record me a minute of audio with it and send me that file. I was able to determine the audio was IMA 4-bit ADPCM encoded, 16-bit audio at 48000hz. Looking at the structure of the file I realized simple placing the header of the good file in front of the data of the bad file should be possible, and lo and behold I had a working file again :)

I'm still very much interested how that ADPCM works and if I can write my own decoder, but that's for another day when I'm strolling on wikipedia again. Have a great day everyone!